# Application driven by url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this application that I am working on that I want to reuse for several websites, the domain model is reused within each of these. Each domain has its own look and feel, but with their own sets of data using said domain model. Is it possible to create a single ASP.NET MVC app that can display the relevant content based on a URL? So if I connect with url x it retrieves data for it and if I connect to url y then it retrieves data for it, all from a single web app. It will seem like different urls to the end user though. What type of mechanisms can and should I use? Would a simple Context.Request work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look what the `Request.Url` is in the Controller Action and then pull back data to the domain model as appropriate. You can even return different Views based on the `Request.Url` too of course. Depends exactly how you want this to function but you can easily customize the Model and View based on the `Request.Url`.